# Develop a function which takes consideration of current state $x$ and first time derivative of the state $\dot{x}$

Tags: functions, derivatives

I would like to develop a function $f$ which take consider of current state $x$ and the first time derivative of state $\dot{x}$ for decision making $\alpha \in [0,1]$ (Whether the system behave good ($\alpha = 1$) and the system behaves bad $\alpha = 0$).

$\alpha = f(x,\dot{x})$

Here are some functions $f$ I could think about:

1. $\alpha = min(x,\dot{x})$
2. $\alpha = x \times \dot{x}$
3. $\alpha = \lambda \times x + (1 - \lambda) \times \dot{x}$

My math foundation is bad. I would appreciate anyone could suggest me more sophisticated function $f$.

Comment: I don't think you want the second one, that will give positive $\alpha$ for when both $x<0$ and $\dot{x} < 0.$ Anyway this kind of makes me think of the sigmoid function, have you heard of it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

Comment: @StephenDonovan I actually use the sigmoid function (x) and sigmoid function ($\dot{x}$), I wonder whether there is more sophisticated way?